# Big Data Algorithm Validation legal issues

Tags: database, bigdata

I am at the beginning of my personal **big data project**.

In the end -after I have implemented a specific algorithm- I want to **validate** my algorithm.

Unfortunately in order to validate the output of my algorithm, I am in need of **personal information**, such as:

1. Name, Surname
2. Occupation/Job
3. Organization name
4. Age
5. Location
6. Years of working experience
7. Income per month/year

---

So my question is:

**How can I collect data without violating laws?**

---

My thoughts on the question:

I know there are business-oriented social networks like **LinkedIn** or **Xing**, but I need **additional information** like income, which is not available through the social networks APIs or is illegal to store and use.